# Filling cell based on existing cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in following format:

```
8A564   nan         json
8A928   nan         json
8A563   nan         json
8A564   10616280    json
8A563   10616222    json
8A564   nan         json
8B1BB   10982483    json
8A564   10616280    json
```

I would like to fill data in second column to match row that has same first column and non null value in second. So I would get following:

```
8A564   10616280    json
8A928   nan         json
8A563   10616222    json
8A564   10616280    json
8A563   10616222    json
8A564   10616280    json
8B1BB   10982483    json
8A564   10616280    json
```

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Is the pairing between the 1st and 2nd column 1:1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `groupby` and `bfill`

Keep in mind the the `0` in `groupby(0)` refers to the column named `0`.  If your column has a different name, use that.

```
df.groupby(0).bfill()

       0         1     2
0  8A564  10616280  json
1  8A928       NaN  json
2  8A563  10616222  json
3  8A564  10616280  json
4  8A563  10616222  json
5  8A564  10616280  json
6  8B1BB  10982483  json
7  8A564  10616280  json
```

---

If the ordering of what is null doesn't lend itself to back filling, you can get the first non-null value.

```
df[1] = df.groupby(0)[1].transform('first')
df

       0         1     2
0  8A564  10616280  json
1  8A928       NaN  json
2  8A563  10616222  json
3  8A564  10616280  json
4  8A563  10616222  json
5  8A564  10616280  json
6  8B1BB  10982483  json
7  8A564  10616280  json
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a python one-liner to help you.

`df.iloc[:, [0,1]].groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x[1].fillna( np.nan if len(x[1].dropna()) == 0 else x[1].dropna().mode()[0])).reset_index()[[0,1]]`

It uses group-by and also fills only if certain condition is met.